# IIS default document feature doesn't work if the directory is hidden

Tags: iis, internal-server-error

I use IIS (Version 10.0.19041.1) where I've configured the website `"www.exampledomain.com"` pointing to the directory `"D:\WWW\"`. As default document I've configured `"index.php"` so that the file `"D:\WWW\test\index.php"` is opened when I call `"http://www.exampledomain.com/test"`. This works perfectly.
But if I now set the directory `"D:\WWW\test\"` to "Hidden" (only the directory and not the files), I get the error message "500 - Internal server error" when I call `"http://www.exampledomain.com/test"`.
But when I call `"http://www.exampledomain.com/test/index.php"` it still works.
Why does the default document feature stop working when the directory is hidden and how can I fix this problem?

Many thanks and regards
Seeky

Comment: [IIS does not GET hidden files](https://serverfault.com/questions/1050789/iis-does-not-get-hidden-files) over on Server Fault says that IIS simply does not serve hidden files and the solution is to not hide the files.

Comment: I'm not talking about hidden files. I wonder why the default document feature no longer works when the directory is hidden. If I specify the file, everything still works fine.

Answer (score 2):

When IIS processes a default document request, it first checks for the existence of the directory. If a directory is set to be hidden, IIS will not be able to find the directory, throwing an error.

When you visit `"http://www.exampledomain.com/test/index.php"`, IIS does not need to check the existence of the directory, because you provide the full file path, it can directly locate the file `"D:\www\test\index.php"`. So even if the directory is set to hidden, the files can still be found and accessed.

Comment: So there's no way to force IIS to open the default document even if the directory is hidden? The directory is known, because I specify it with `"http://www.exampledomain.com/test"`.

Comment: but this is not the full file path